# How to uncheck a checkbox using jQuery without triggering click event

Tags: jquery

Normally people complain about checkbox clicking not triggering any event but in my case it's opposite, I want to uncheck checkbox without triggering any click event on it.

This is my precious checkbox,

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="someID" runat="server" Text="myCheckBoxText" OnClick="DoSomething();" />
```

Comment: `uncheck checkbox without triggering any click event on it` does this mean at page load.

Comment: @Jai Nope, not at page load, it's when something happens in a dragable lists, I need to uncheck checkbox without click

Answer (score 9):

You can use **[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)**:

```
//Un-check
$("#someID").prop("checked",false);

//check
$("#someID").prop("checked",true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
//check
$("#someID").prop("checked",true);

//Un-check
$("#someID").prop("checked",false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's asp.net you can use `.prop()` along with the following script

```
$('#<%=someID.clientID %>').prop('checked',false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$('input[id$="someID"]').prop('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

My experience with bootstrap 4.4.1 and jQuery 1.12.1 was that the click event got triggered on .prop("checked", ...) and .prop("indeterminate", ...). Thus the only reliable way to set the indeterminate state was with an ugly button alongside the checkbox or to set up an image box to change image with every click instead of the checkbox. Turning off the event handler did not work because it got triggered after it was turned back on again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).